# How to sleep or block execution in a async method. Thread.Sleep doesn't work

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an async method that has a signature like:

```
public static async void Run(..)
{
  //..
  var responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(..);
  // ..
   using (Stream stream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
   //...

   Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

I can this method inside of my console app like this:

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {
     for(int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
     {
        Run(...);
     }  
 }
```

I want to block/sleep inside of my Run method because of rate limiting, how can I do this?

I tried this:

```
 public static async void Run(...)
    {
      // ...
       Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

But this didn't seem to do anything.
Can someone explain why this didn't work and the correct way?

Comment: Do you have an `await` somewhere in the `Run()`?

Comment: @AnoopRDesai I updated my run method with more details

Comment: `async` and threads don't really play well.  You should be using `Task.Delay` when you want a task to stop for a while, but that isn't really your problem.   It sounds like you want to queue up a number of tasks, but only run a few at a time.  Is that correct?

Comment: An advice from the official docs: [avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.8) when using the `async` pattern:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   for(int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
   {
      await Run(...);
   }  
}

public static async Task Run(...)
{
  // ...
  await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

NOTE: I've also changed your `Run` method to be `async` so that it can be awaited. Also, `async void` is generally a bad idea and should typically only be done when writing event handlers.

Comment: I am looping Run, so I WANT them to run sequentially....i.e. I want only 1 Run method to me running at a time.  sleep for x seconds, then the next one should run.

Comment: @Blankman - That's what will happen. The await on `Run` means the next iteration of the loop won't happen until `Run` has completed.

Comment: btw, if I wanted to return right away earlier in the function can I just call return like normal?